# Right way to configure JPA to work with any JPA implementation

Tags: java, jpa, persistence, config

I have built a small application. Now I’m looking for the right way to deal with the JPA configuration.

My app use JPA 2.0 to connect to a database. Right now the configuration is hardcoded in my persistence.xml file. When I built the jar file, my persistence.xml is included in the jar.

So my questions are:

- How do I configure my app/JPA to work with any JPA implementation.
- And how can I use the same jar as a standalone application and as a component to deploy on a server (eg. Glassfish)

Answer (score 0):

First of all JPA is a specification, which is being implemented by the ORM framework providers such as Hibernate, Eclipselink etc.

To make your application compatible with any implementation of JPA, you should strictly follow JPA specifications, you should not be using any ORM vendor specific features, this will allow your application to work with any ORM framework, however you have to specify the dialect class by your self to interact with a particular database.

One thing you can do here is write a properties file which will have all the database name with corrosponding dialect class for that particular database, you can ask user to choose the database and can fetch the related class name(Dialect class name) from the properties file.

About using the same application as standalone and using it as a component to deploy on a server, I am sorry but I am not getting your point.

Comment: I thought of something like Jenkins. You can run it form the command line (java -jar jenkins.war) or deploy it on a Server. 
In my case I can execute it from the command line or use it in a web application. On the webserver the application should use the JPA implementation and configuration from the Server.